# Call an api when order status changes

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce in my project, I'm trying to call an API every time order status changes from "pending payment" to "processing".
I'm looking for an action to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code:

```
function mysite_processing($order_id) {
    //your api call here
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'mysite_processing');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "woocommerce_order_status_changed" hook as below,

**$this_get_id** : Order ID

**$this_status_transition_from** : Order status changing from

**$this_status_transition_to** : Order status changing to

**$instance** : Order object instance

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','action_woocommerce_order_status_changed',10, 4 );
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $this_get_id, $this_status_transition_from, $this_status_transition_to, $instance ) { 
    // your code
}
```